# Difference between lazy evaluation and promises/futures

Tags: language-agnostic, promise, lazy-evaluation, future

What's the difference between a `promise` or `future` and a `lazily evaluated function/object`?

They both act like a placeholder for a deferred computation, and I understand that the principles that they operate on are different, but what's the actual difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both promises and "lazily evaluated objects" are forms of **proxies**. [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) is the key word here. A proxy means "a placeholder for an actual object value"

- A promise is a time constrained (temporal) proxy for a value. Some libraries like Kris Kowal's Q-Connection even let you proxy remote object with promises, and there is a lot of fascinating research (really!) about this use case in hostile conditions made by Mark Miller. This was actually the original motivation for promises (to deal with network latency).
- A lazy evaluated object is a proxy for a value to postpone evaluation to the point you *have* to do it.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer (esp. the term "synchronicity constrained"). Are you in effect saying that lazy evaluation is based on synchronous proxies, while futures are asynchronous proxies?

Comment: @stakx wow, I phrased myself in a very weird way there! I'll rephrase to "time constrained". Thanks!

Comment: "... hostile conditions made by Mark Miller". Do we have a reference please - I would like to understand the hostile conditions that Mark Miller made?